Measurability of conditional quotient of measurable functions
Let $(X,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space and let $\mathcal B$ denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the real interval $[0,1]$. For two measurable functions $f,g~\colon X \to [0,1]$, define the conditional quotient $f \mathbin{/\mkern-6mu/} g$ of $f$ and $g$ as the function
$$ f \mathbin{/\mkern-6mu/} g ~\colon X \to [0,1], \quad x \mapsto 
\begin{cases} 
  f(x) / g(x) & \text{if }g(x) \neq 0\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I need to know that this function is measurable.
To prove it, I will show that the pre-image of an interval $[0,c]$ under $f \mathbin{/\mkern-6mu/} g$ is a measurable set for any $c \in [0,1]$.
If $c = 0$ then this pre-image is the measurable set $f^{-1}(0) \cup g^{-1}(0)$, since $(f \mathbin{/\mkern-6mu/} g )(x) = 0$ iff $f(x)=0$ or if $g(x)=0$ (or both).
Otherwise, if $c > 0$, then the pre-image $\{x : (f \mathbin{/\mkern-6mu/} g) (x) \leq c\}$ is equal to the measurable set $\{x : f(x) \leq g(x) \cdot c\} \cup g^{-1}(0)$. This is because $(f\mathbin{/\mkern-6mu/}g)(x) \leq c$ iff either $g(x)=0$ or $f(x)/g(x)\leq c$.
This conditional thing to escape division by zero always feels like cheating. I really need someone to reassure me and say that this this is a perfectly fine proof.
PS: using short-hand notation $\{ f \leq h \}$ with $h = g\cdot c$ for the set $\{x : f(x) \leq g(x) \cdot c\}$ above, this set is measurable because it is the complement of
$$\{h < f\} = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]} \{ h < q < f \}=\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]} \{ h < q \} \cap \{ q < f \}$$
